# Does MiniMagick and Carrierwave Work On Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have been unable to definitively find out if MiniMagick and Carrierwave actually work in a Ruby on Rails application running on Windows (I'm running Windows 8)

I develop with someone who uses a Mac, and they have no problems uploading images to the application using the same setup ( I know Ruby is much nicer to work with on Mac OS) I've spent countless hours trying different versions of ImageMagick, different configurations etc.. all to no avail.No errors, no nothing! All I've managed to establish is that everything works perfect until any commands to create thumbnails/resize are tried.

Then I found these links http://rubyforge.org/projects/mini-magick
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/407

Where it states that the operating system is MacOS and POSIX. No sign of Windows here.. so does that mean I'll never get MiniMagick and Carrierwave working?

The reason I'm looking for a definitive answer here is because I've stumbled across a few threads here which have been about people trying to get a simliar setup working on Windows
[Rails - WIndows 7 carrierwave, minimagick resize not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779801/rails-windows-7-carrierwave-minimagick-resize-not-working)

But this was never solved as far as I can tell.

I'm also still curious because the original github issue is dated 3 years ago, so this could be an out of date version they were talking about?

If it helps I'm running Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.1 with ImageMagick 6.8.9-Q16

Hopefully someone can give me a definitive answer an put my mind to rest even if it's bad news!

Answer (score 1):

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'mini_magick', github: 'minimagick/minimagick', ref: '6d0f8f953112cce6324a524d76c7e126ee14f392'
```

This worked for me in windows 8... 6 months ago, maybe? I am on mac now, so have no way of testing if it's still the applicable.

Comment: @Mallanga, I've updated my gemfile to reflect that, but unfortunately it's still not working. Can you remember if you were using any commands like `process :resize_to_fit` or `version :thumbnail` and if they were working ok? This seems to be where mines failing